# Package the .Net redistributable in my burn bootstrapper

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.9

I'm trying to package the .Net 4.5.2 redistributable into my burn application, by following the instructions on this [page](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html).

But it fails to find the file in the temp burn location.

According to the log burn tries to find the file here:

```
[0A14:09C4][2015-05-12T16:48:52]w343: Prompt for source of package: NetFx452Redist, payload: NetFx452Redist, path: `C:\Users\simon\Desktop\redist\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe`
```

But the file actually ends up in a temporary folder

eg.

```
C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Temp\{f5207472-d2a0-4b00-b9ee-c535385bde58}\redist\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe
```

The instructions say to do this:

```
<PayloadGroup Id="NetFx452RedistPayload">
  <Payload Name="redist\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
           SourceFile="..\..\Binaries\Microsoft\NetFramework\4.5.2\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"/>
</PayloadGroup>
```

How can I make Burn look in the correct location for the .net installer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than reference `NetFxExtension` you could gain more control by directly referencing the .NET install package:

```
<Fragment>
  <!-- Value of the 'Release' registry value when .NET 4.5.2 is installed -->
  <?define NetFx452MinRelease = 379893 ?>

  <!-- Get the release of the .NET V4 framework currently installed -->
  <util:RegistrySearch
        Id="NETFRAMEWORK4"
        Variable="NETFRAMEWORK4"
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
        Value="Release"
        Result="value" />

  <!-- Install .NET 4.5.2 if not already installed -->
  <PackageGroup Id="NetFx4FullRedist">
    <ExePackage
        Id="NetFx4FullRedist"
        Cache="no"
        Compressed="yes"
        InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;"
        RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;"
        UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;"
        PerMachine="yes"
        DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK4 &gt;= $(var.NetFx452MinRelease)"
        Vital="yes"
        Permanent="yes"
        Protocol="netfx4"
        SourceFile="..\..\Binaries\Microsoft\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
        Name="Redist\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe">
    </ExePackage>
  </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Then reference `NetFx4FullRedist` in your `<chain>..</chain>`:

```
  <!-- .NET runtime full profile -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx4FullRedist"/>
```

I've used a variation on this to include the .NET 4 Client redistributable into my burn generated installer application without any issues.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an ExePackage element for the DotNet framework will work, but it is also possible to use the PayloadGroup:

```
<PayloadGroup Id="NetFx452RedistPayload">
    <Payload Name="redist\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
             SourceFile="X:\path\to\redists\in\repo\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"/>
<PayloadGroup/>
```

Reference this group so that it is included in your payload:

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
  <PayloadGroupRef Id="NetFx452RedistPayload"/>
```

You also need to add a reference to NetFx452Redist in your chain:

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx452Redist" />
```

During the Apply phase, the source will fail to resolve (unless you have NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe in a folder named "redist" relative to your bundle). To point to the NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe included in your payload, the trick is to add an event handler for the ResolveSource event.

ResolveSource += ResolveSourceHandler;

```
  private void ResolveSourceHandler(object sender, ResolveSourceEventArgs args)
  {
     try
     {
        //Everything from the "CurrentBundle" class is from my model.
        //The model is built from parsing BootstrapperApplicationData.xml.
        //Specifically, payload comes from WixPayloadProperties.
        var payload = CurrentBundle.PayloadList.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Compare(x.Id, args.PayloadId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
        var newPayloadPath = (payload != null) ? Path.Combine(CurrentBundle.WorkingFolder, payload.Name) : string.Empty;

        if (File.Exists(newPayloadPath))
        {
           Engine.SetLocalSource(args.PackageOrContainerId, args.PayloadId, newPayloadPath);
           args.Result = Result.Retry;
        }
        else if (File.Exists(args.LocalSource) == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.DownloadSource) == false)
        {
           args.Result = Result.Download;
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        args.Result = Result.Error;
     }
  }
```

Comment: CurrentBundle.WorkingFolder is the folder where BootstrapperApplicationData.xml is located.

Comment: Hi Gerhard can you shed some light on how\where to write the ResolveSource event handler? Is this in a custom action project somewhere?

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I'm writing a managed bootstrapper application.  The ResolveSource event is called during the Apply phase.  In your class that inherits from BootstrapperApplication, you should be able to type "ResolveSource += " and Visual Studio intellisense should pick up the fact that the "ResolveSource" event exists.

Comment: Thanks Gerhard. This is useful information. Although I have managed to circumvent my issue at present but I will be sure to use this. I was creating an installer for TMO (http://gotmo.co.uk) but the journey has been rather tough because of sparse Wix documentation.